# Finding isometries of a manifold $M$ which has Euclidean geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, isometry

> How do you find the isometries of a manifold $M$ with metric $ds^2=\frac{du^2}{u^2}+\frac{dv^2}{v^2}?$

Observe that $ds^2$ is of the form $ds^2=g(u)du^2+f(v)dv^2.$ This means that the metric must describe a Euclidean geometry. In fact with more work we can show that $ds^2$ is a transported metric from the familiar $\Bbb R^2$ to $M:=\Bbb R^2_+$ via $\exp.$ I calculated the pullback via an immersion here:

\begin{align}
 (f^{-1})^* (dx^2 + dy^2) &=( d((f^{-1})^*x))^2 + ( d((f^{-1})^*y))^2 \\
&= (d (x\circ f^{-1}))^2 +(d (y\circ f^{-1}))^2 \\
&= (d \log u)^2 +(d\log v)^2 \\
&= \left( \frac{1}{u} du\right)^2 +  \left( \frac{1}{v} dv\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{u^2} du^2 + \frac{1}{v^2} dv^2.
\end{align}

Now I know that the isometries of $M$ are basically the isometries of $\Bbb R^2$ in disguise.

I figured out that translation in $\Bbb R^2 \implies (x+a,y+b)$ has analogue in $M \implies (ax,by).$

> Rotation in $\Bbb R^2 \implies
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\  
> \sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
> \end{bmatrix}(x,y)$ has what analogue in $M?$

I couldn't figure this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have shown that:
\begin{align}
f \colon (\mathbb{R}_+^*\times \mathbb{R}_+^*,g) &\longrightarrow (\mathbb{R}^2,\mathrm{can})\\
(u,v) & \longmapsto (\ln u, \ln v)
\end{align}
is an isometry. Let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $R_{\theta}$ be the corresponding rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then:

\begin{align}f^*R_{\theta}(u,v) &= f^{-1} \left(R_{\theta}f(u,v)\right)\\
&= f^{-1}\left(\cos \theta \ln u +\sin\theta \ln v, -\sin \theta \ln u + \cos \theta \ln v \right) \\
 &= \left(\exp \left(\cos \theta \ln u +\sin\theta \ln v \right), \exp\left( -\sin \theta \ln u + \cos \theta \ln v\right) \right)\\
&= (u^{\cos \theta}v^{\sin \theta}, u^{-\sin\theta}v^{\cos\theta}).
\end{align}

Also, translations $(x,y) \mapsto (x+a,y+b)$ become $(u,v)\mapsto (e^au,e^bv)$.